# Android Setting Wallpaper with service chooser

Tags: android

I am developing an application which have a lot of wallpapers in it.
I want to build a dialog that will appears when the user clicks on the images , and ask the user which service to use for setting wallpaper. (home screen, home and lock screen , whatsup , etc.)

I have found the solution by myself , here is my code ;

```
File f = new File(path);  //  
                Uri picUri = Uri.fromFile(f);  
                Intent setAs = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
                setAs.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
                //setAs.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,picUri);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(setAs, "Set As"), 0);
```